# Kendo multiselect change TagTemplate based on number of selected items

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

Let say i have a multi-select that displays 'A-Animation', 'B-Brutal', etc,etc,etc.
i am utilizing the TagTemplate feature to set the text displayed as above.

How do i make the selected text to be 'A-Animation' for single selection, and 'A,B,C,D' for multiple selection?

Answer (score 0):

Moru, you'll need to build some conditional logic into your template. This example does something similar, showing an icon and text while there are less than three selections, before switching into only showing a collection of icons. Hopefully it will give you some ideas :)

```
<script id="tag-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # var fullTag = (values.length < 3); #
    # for (var idx = 0; idx < values.length; idx++) { #
        # var di = dataItems[idx]; #
        <span class="far fa-fw #:di.icon#" title="#:di.text#"></span>
        # if (fullTag) { #
            #:di.text#
            # if (idx < values.length - 1) {#, # } #
        # } #
    # } #
    # if (!fullTag) { #
        of #:maxTotal#
    # } #
</script>
```